# MongoDB - How to make a query to get the average usage?

Tags: sql, mongodb, robo3t, database

Here is how the documents in db look like.

```
/* 1 */
{
  "_id" : 1,
  "feat" : {
      "processName": [
         {
            "value" : {
                 "value": "Process1"
             }
         }
       ],
      "processUsage": [
         {
            "value" : {
                 "value": 23.21
             }
         }
       ]
   }
}

/* 2 */
{
  "_id" : 2,
  "feat" : {
      "processName": [
         {
            "value" : {
                 "value": "Process2"
             }
         }
       ],
      "memoryUsage": [
         {
            "value" : {
                 "value": 2.411502e+05
             }
         }
       ]
   }
}

/* 3 */
{
  "_id" : 3,
  "feat" : {
      "processName": [
         {
            "value" : {
                 "value": "Process1"
             }
         }
       ],
      "processUsage": [
         {
            "value" : {
                 "value": 67.42
             }
         }
       ]
   }
}

/* 4 */
{
  "_id" : 4,
  "feat" : {
      "processName": [
         {
            "value" : {
                 "value": "Process3"
             }
         }
       ],
      "processUsage": [
         {
            "value" : {
                 "value": 39.97
             }
         }
       ]
   }
}

/* 5 */
{
  "_id" : 5,
  "feat" : {
      "processName": [
         {
            "value" : {
                 "value": "Process2"
             }
         }
       ],
      "processUsage": [
         {
            "value" : {
                 "value": 21.05
             }
         }
       ]
   }
}
```

Each process has entries with processUsage and memoryUsage. What I am interest in is the average processUsage. So, I'd like to ignore the entries with memoryUsage.

I tried $match + $group in an aggregate with $avg, but for each process I just got back as average 0.00000000.
Then I tried my luck with mapReduce using javascript, unfortunately it did not work out either.

Could someone just show me how to do that? By the way, I am using Robomongo 0.8.5

Edit:

The query looks like this:

```
db.database.aggregate([
    { $match : {"$feat.processUsage.value.value": {$gt : -1} 
    },
    {
      $group: {_id: "$feats.processName.value.value", average: {$avg:  
           "$feats.processUsage.value.value"}
    }
])
```

Comment: Can you show the query that you tried?

Comment: @toddmo: I added the query.

Comment: You are grouping on the wrong basis. You'll need an identifier that'll distinguish memory from process. Then group by it.

Comment: @tumbler what you want to average all  `processUsage` data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following aggregate query:

```
db.test.aggregate(
  [
    { 
       $unwind : "$feat.processUsage"
    },
    {
       $group: {
         _id: "$feat.processName.value.value",
         average: {$avg:"$feat.processUsage.value.value"}
        }
    }
  ]
)
```

Unwinding in the initial phase will let you filter documents that has processUsage key in document.

Result:

```
{ "_id" : [ "Process2" ], "average" : 21.05 }
{ "_id" : [ "Process3" ], "average" : 39.97 }
{ "_id" : [ "Process1" ], "average" : 45.315 }
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. Could you show me by chance, how to calculate the standard deviation in robomongo, too?

Comment: standard deviation in aggregation is available in mongoDB 3.1.5. Check this out: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5044. As a work around you need to do map reduce in current stable release as described in https://gist.github.com/RedBeard0531/1886960